# Ruby - React Web app element found but not interactable

Tags: ruby, reactjs, selenium-webdriver

This is my first time writing automated test for React App. I use Ruby Selenium Webdriver. I'm trying to find this element `<i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-cog">::before</i>`

```
<thead>...</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr id="coach56">...</tr>
    <tr id="coach88">
        <td>...</td>
        <td class="text-right">
            <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-cog">::before</i>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

and click on it

```
table = @browser.find_element(:css, 'table.table')
rows = table.find_elements(:tag_name, 'tr')
cog = rows.last.find_elements(:tag_name, 'td').last.find_element(:tag_name, 'i')
```

Even though my webdriver could find the element just fine (when I do `pp cog`)

```
#<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x..fb0ec34323433b358 id="1a0b9a5e-a789-cf4c-9de2-d140d628bb43">
```

When I tried clicking on it `cog.click` I get this error

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotInteractableError:
stack backtrace:
   0:        0x106a3abc4 - backtrace::backtrace::trace::h6e3f5d4ff9dcd09c
   1:        0x106a3af9f - backtrace::capture::Backtrace::new::he142908a5a8f9eda
   2:        0x1066cb3ef - webdriver::error::WebDriverError::new::h11cfe73261fd6398
   3:        0x1066d8932 - geckodriver::marionette::MarionetteSession::response::hf1e03dba1b51e3d2
   4:        0x1066e7a9a - geckodriver::marionette::MarionetteConnection::send_command::h198264f6a411d523
   5:        0x1066d7238 - _$LT$geckodriver..marionette..MarionetteHandler$u20$as$u20$webdriver..server..WebDriverHandler$LT$geckodriver..marionette..GeckoExtensionRoute$GT$$GT$::handle_command::h1ce60025abbb1e2f
   6:        0x106660233 - _$LT$webdriver..server..Dispatcher$LT$T$C$$u20$U$GT$$GT$::run::h91f334bc53d085f2
   7:        0x1066cc00a - webdriver::server::start::_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$::h2009c93c17caa760
   8:        0x1065c3fda - std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace::h7e6fc63778e17700
   9:        0x1065d51e3 - std::thread::Builder::spawn::_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$::_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$::h9046a824429b7834
  10:        0x106582faa - _$LT$std..panic..AssertUnwindSafe$LT$F$GT$$u20$as$u20$core..ops..function..FnOnce$LT$$LP$$RP$$GT$$GT$::call_once::h7c96f21f7f4901f2
  11:        0x1065d6029 - std::panicking::try::do_call::hd2ff6fc209e7ca99
  12:        0x106d5caec - __rust_maybe_catch_panic
  13:        0x1065d5bdc - std::panicking::try::h56209e5aa6d1fe14
  14:        0x1065d2a05 - std::panic::catch_unwind::h9b8731248ee7a1e3
  15:        0x1065d4f2e - std::thread::Builder::spawn::_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$::hf264dcc876d92ec3
  16:        0x106642bf3 - _$LT$F$u20$as$u20$alloc..boxed..FnBox$LT$A$GT$$GT$::call_box::h9197fed04f7f649b
  17:        0x106d58d5b - std::sys::imp::thread::Thread::new::thread_start::h7c0954aeccca31ea
  18:     0x7fff9d27b93a - _pthread_body
  19:     0x7fff9d27b886 - _pthread_start
/Users/trea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@trea/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:71:in `assert_ok'
/Users/trea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@trea/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:34:in `initialize'
/Users/trea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@trea/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:83:in `new'
/Users/trea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@trea/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:83:in `create_response'
/Users/trea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@trea/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:106:in `request'
/Users/trea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@trea/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:61:in `call'
/Users/trea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@trea/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:170:in `execute'
/Users/trea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@trea/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c/bridge.rb:537:in `execute'
/Users/trea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@trea/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c/bridge.rb:360:in `click_element'
/Users/trea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@trea/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/element.rb:74:in `click'
```

Any suggestion to resolve this? I have also tried to hover the element first then click it but also got the same error on clicking.

Thank you

Comment: What's the full result of `p cog.inspect`?

Comment: `pp cog.inpsect` gives `"#<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x22934ba814a6414e id=\"86191fee-3e91-e24b-8960-76b0cd004d12\">"`